# Ubuntu 20.04 DNS 100% Packet loss despite no changes to Router or PC

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dns

First time asking a question on this forum.

So I was using a dell Inspiron 5547 with Ethernet. Recently I had to change my router’s location so I had to switch from Ethernet to 5ghz WiFi. Now I am unable to receive incoming pings.
I have made no modifications to any firewall or related settings on both the PC and router. The only change I made prior to this was trying out Adobe Acrobat Reader with wine. The PC was alright post uninstalling it too.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Results in x transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time x.

```
ping www.google.com
```

Results in same as above.

Pinging 192.168.1.1 which is my router gateway ip works fine.

Pinging anything else does not work.

Based on other forum posts I tried traceroute but I do not have net-tools installed and have no way of doing so AFAIK.

I tried to move the laptop and use Ethernet but the same problem occurs on Ethernet and USB Tethering as well.

Apt-get update and --fix-missing also don’t work.

Everything works perfectly when i rebooted into a live usb version of ubuntu.

Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

Thanks,
N

Edit:

Results for

```
ip route


0.0.0.0/1 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97 
default via 100.85.0.1 dev pvpnksintrfe proto static metric 98
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2se proto dhcp metric 600
100.85.0.0/24 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto kernel scope link src 100.85.0.1 metric 97
100.85.0.0/24 dev pvpnksintrfe proto kernel scope link src 100.85.0.1 metric 98
128.0.0.0/2 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97 
169.254.0.0/16 dev pvpnroutintrfe scope link metric 1000
192.0.0.0/7 dev pvpnroutintrfo proto static scope link metric 97 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2se proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 600
194.0.0.0/8 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.0.0.0/9 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.128.0.0/11 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.160.0.0/12 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.176.0.0/14 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
195.180.0.0/16 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.0.0/17 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.128.0/19 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.160.0/23 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.162.0/25 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.162.128/27 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
195.181.162.160/31 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
195.181.162.162 dev pvpnroutintrfo proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.162.164/30 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.162.168/29 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.162.176/28 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
195.181.162.192/26 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.163.0/24 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.164.0/22 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.168.0/21 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.176.0/20 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.181.192.0/18 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
195.182.0.0/15 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
195.184.0.0/13 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
195.192.0.0/10 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
196.0.0.0/6 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
200.0.0.0/5 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
208.0.0.0/4 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link metric 97
224.0.0.0/3 dev pvpnroutintrfe proto static scope link netric 97
```

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about a desktop (NetworkManager) or server (netplan), but it maybe because you had static routing (a *live* system defaults to DHCP) thus you need to change the static routing to match your change.   You could try `ping 8.8.8.8` to see if you can ping google (using non-addresses not human names, ie. if that works you have DNS issues which translates google.com into numbered-addresses), or commands like `ip route` to view routing detail etc.   But start with server? desktop?

Comment: Hi, It is a desktop, a Dell Inspiron PC

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that ping 8.8.8.8 also resulted in 100% packet loss... Have modified the post

Comment: Well the os is also a desktop type: so its network manager.

Comment: What to you get for `ip route`?

Comment: Doug Smythies, I have updated the post…

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Switching between wired (Ethernet) and Wireless is NOT "no changes".

Comment: Yeah I get that but what I left out was I did use wireless occasionally. Just before switching even.

Comment: Waltinator what do I look for? Sorry I am a newbie

Comment: I do not understand your routing table, but shouldn't this `default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2se proto dhcp metric 600` be first?

Comment: @Doug Smythies I dunno… How do I change it if so?

Comment: @DougSmythies hello? You there?

Comment: Yes, I am here. I do not know how to change it.